# Image is not showing on image view React native

Tags: image, react-native, view

I am developing a react native project I want to show images from a collection of URLs that are retrieved from firebase and stored in an array Using below code

```
{/* //==================================================== */}

<View style={styles.container}>
    <View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'column'}}>
            <Text>ProductName</Text>
            <Text>ProductName</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}/>
                <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}}/>
                <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}}/>
            </View>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                {/* <View style={{width: 200, height: 200, backgroundColor: 'green'}} /> */}
                {imageUrls.map((item, i) => console.log("Swiper inside Item:" + i + " " + item))}
                <Swiper>{
                    imageUrls.map((item, i) =>

                        <View>
                            <FullWidthImage source={{uri: item}} key={i}/>
                        </View>
                    )}</Swiper>
            </View>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}/>
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
</View>

{/* //==================================================== */}

<Swiper>{
    imageUrls.map((item, i) =>
        <View>
            <FullWidthImage source={{uri: item}} key={i}/>
        </View>
    )}
</Swiper>
```

> The swaiper code shown below is working fine and showing the images,
>   but the swaiper code above is not working. The array imageUrls is not
>   empty at any part of the code. I checked it using a console.

Comment: Comparing to your working version, I see you put 2 'map's. you should log the content of the 2nd map to see what are you passing/getting. Possibly the second map returns empty content so never show any thing.

Comment: @AliBakhtiar The swaiper inside the flux is not working. but outside the flux its working

Comment: Post your FullWidthImage code

Comment: @sfratini import FullWidthImage from 'react-native-fullwidth-image'  this is it. even if I use <Image> its not working.

Comment: Try to give the surrounding view and image a style with a defined height and width

Comment: @sfratini   container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#f5f6f8',
      padding:10
    },

Comment: @sfratini  I tried this line and it worked correctly <View style={{width: 200, height: 200, backgroundColor: 'green'}} />  ....... But not swaiper

Comment: Probably this line too                 {imageUrls.map((item, i) => console.log("Swiper inside Item:" + i + " " + item))} remove that console log in the middle of the tags. Also are you sure the imageMaps has actualy data?